# Count of childrens 1-* children *-* Linq Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I am a bit new to LINQ and EF and was trying to get the total count of students in each class taught be each teacher in the below database. I want to output the teacher name followed by the class name and then the count of students in that class. I can't embed images due to no rep, sorry.

[image]

I am unsure how to do this as when I try to use two from statements I get a  type Inference failed. When I try to use a join and join Teacher.id on Class.TeachersId I get an error saying "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'"

The Models of the Class and Teacher tables are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something like this should work:

```
foreach (var teacher in context.Teachers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The teacher '{0}' is teaching the following classes:", 
        teacher.Name);

    foreach (var teacherClass in teacher.Classes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" - {0} ({1} students)", 
            teacherClass.Name, teacherClass.Students.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, so simple I don't know how I didn't think of that.